# Do Optaplanner support CSV file as Input

Tags: optaplanner

As per the document, data can be passed to Optaplanner as XML file.
Right now I am getting data as CSV file.
Could anyone let me know, how to use CSV file as INput.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the example. Take a look a the `FileIO` class of the example you're referring to.